# Dynamic number of calls to a chunk with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have such a list:

```
> lSlopes
$A
  Estimate 2.5 % 97.5 %
1     2.12 -0.56   4.80

$B
  Estimate 2.5 % 97.5 %
1     2.21 -0.68   5.10

$C
  Estimate 2.5 % 97.5 %
1     2.22 -2.21   6.65
```

It has three elements but its length can change (according to the data not shown here). I want to display each element in a chunk.

My first idea was to write a chunk containing a loop calling `knit_child()` at each step, but I don't know how to get the correct rendering with `knit_child()`.

I have find the following solution which works well but which requires two `Rmd` files; the first one calls the second one and the second one recursively calls itself:

**mainfile.Rmd**:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
J <- length(lSlopes)
i <- 1
```

```{r child, child="stepfile.Rmd"}
```
Nice!
````

**stepfile.Rmd**:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
lSlopes[[i]]
i <- i+1
```

```{r child, child="stepfile.Rmd", eval= i <= J}
```
````

This exactly generates the rendering I want:

[image]

I love this tricky solution but I wonder whether there exists a non-recursive solution ?

Comment: By the way there's a problem with this solution if one wants to include some inline R code: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/613

Comment: Plenty of examples at https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples: 020, 069, 075, ... Please feel free to answer your own question after you learn these examples.

Comment: @Yihui, I don't understand why there is the option `include` in the code given in my answer ? There's something strange: actually I knit these files from a Shiny app, and the code produces an unexpected folder with a figure.

Comment: @Yihui Ah ok, I have removed `include=FALSE` and I understand this point. But the folder with the figure is very strange... I'll try to isolate the problem and to post it elsewhere.

Comment: @Yihui I think the strange folder was a consequence that I didn't generate the output in the current directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is the RMarkdown solution analogous to https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/020-for-loop.Rnw, using `knit_child()`. As my solution, it requires two files, but it is much more clear.

**mainfile.Rmd:**

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
J <- length(lSlopes)
```

```{r runall, include=FALSE}
out <- NULL
for (i in 1:J) {
  out <- c(out, knit_child('stepfile.Rmd'))
}
```

`r paste(out, collapse = '\n')` 

Nice!
````

**stepfile.Rmd:**

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
lSlopes[[i]]
```
````