# R markdown rerun the same section of report with different parameter

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm familiar with R markdown "parameters".

However, say I want to generate the same report (same chart, same table) but for 5 different regions.

Is there a way to do this elegantly in a loop or lapply or do I need to make several sections. So in pseudo code I want to do something like:

```
for(i in 1:5):
   Bunch of text
   table[i]
   plot[i]
```

Instead of

```
bunch of text
table[1]
plot[1]

bunch of text
table[2]
plot[2]

...
```

Put another way, I want to functionalize a "section" of the report, and then I can call

```
for(i in 1:5):
   makeReport(i)
```

And it will go in, put in the text, figures, etc associated with index i.

Comment: You can `brew` the document before passing to `knitr` or do both things at one run via `Pandoc.brew` in my [pander package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call print explicitly if inside `for` loop:

````
```{r}
for(i in 1:2) {
  print(summary(cars[,-i]))
  plot(cars[,-i])
}
```
````

or

````
```{r}
makeReport <- function(i) {
  print(summary(cars[,-i]))
  plot(cars[,-i])
}

for(i in 1:2) {
  makeReport(i)
}
```
````

#### Update

As Stéphane Laurent already demonstrated in [Dynamic number of calls to a chunk with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080917/dynamic-number-of-calls-to-a-chunk-with-knitr)

you can define a child .rmd:

**test_section.rmd**

````
Header: `r i`-th cars

```{r}
  print(summary(cars[,-i]))
  plot(cars[,-i])
```
````

and in the main rmd file concatenate the results:

````
```{r runall, include=FALSE}
out <- NULL
for (i in 1:2) {
  out <- c(out, knitr::knit_child('test_section.rmd'))
}
```

`r paste(out, collapse = '\n')`
````

Comment: Yes, but what if I want different headers for each section?

Comment: @user1357015 Put them in a character vector and print the `i`-th element as a first thing?

Comment: Ah, yes... you would have to use `results = "asis"` to format the headings as html - for example `print(htmltools::h3(my_text[i]))`- and this may get complicated.

Comment: Right -- at that point things get really complex -- what I'm hoping for is some way to do it more elegantly in R markdown. :-).

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080917/dynamic-number-of-calls-to-a-chunk-with-knitr

Comment: thanks for that link. It got me rolling :-). I'll mark your answer correct.