# Create RMarkdown chuncks in a loop

Tags: r, loops, r-markdown

I would like to be able to create RMarkdown chuncks in a loop. I have tried doing this through a `for` loop, without much success. I imagine this could probably be possible through `lapply`, as one would do for creating `UIs` in a shiny app. However, I haven't had any success so far.

**Reprex:**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: tango
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- datasets::iris %>% 
  dplyr::as_tibble()
```

## setosa

```{r}
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point()
```

## versicolor

```{r}
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Species == "versicolor") %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point()
```

## virginica

```{r}
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Species == "virginica") %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point()
```
````

My goal is to create the headings (setosa, versicolor, and virginica) and the chuncks with a loop.

For example:

```
for(i in c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")) {

  ## i

  df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Species == i) %>% 
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_point()
}
```

Any ideas on how accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need the repeated code to show up in the output? Or do you just need to have the heading for each group, and then the resulting plot under that?

Comment: just the heading and the resulting plot :)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080917/dynamic-number-of-calls-to-a-chunk-with-knitr) is what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create headings + outputs within a loop, you can do:

````
```{r species_loop, results='asis'}
for(i in c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")) {

  cat(paste0("\n\n## ", i, "\n"))

  p <- df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Species == i) %>% 
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
    ggplot2::geom_point()
  print(p)
}
```
````

So:

- Using `results='asis'` to allow output that you `cat()` to be interpreted as Markdown syntax
- `cat()`ing the required markdown syntax to produce the headers (surrounded by some newlines to make sure it's interpreted properly)
- Explicitly `print()`ing the plot within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

A function based on `cat` would replicate your chunks for every iris species. For the one-time chunks use single `cat`s.

````
FUN <- function(x) cat("\n##", x, "
```{r}
df %>%
  dplyr::filter(Species == ",x, ") %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point()
```\n")
````

To produce the shown `.Rmd` file, you could use `sink`. (For sake of brevity I'll omit the header here.)

````
sink(file="iris.Rmd")  ## start `sink`

cat("```{r}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- datasets::iris %>% 
  dplyr::as_tibble()
```")

invisible(sapply(c("'setosa'", "'versicolor'", "'virginica'"), FUN))

sink()  ## end `sink`
````

You'll find your `.Rmd` file in your working directory (`getwd()`).